# Comparing files in eclipse show same whitespaces as different

Tags: eclipse

Why does the compare files in Eclipse show difference between an identical line that starts and/or stops with white spaces?

Why would anyone ever want this "feature" anyway, all lines become marked as different. Must be a bug.

I know I can use the ignore white spaces setting, but then it ignores the differens in block indentation as well and I don't want that.

[image]

Comment: Are you really, really sure the whitespace is identical? For the Tabs it could be that the left ones are tabulators and the right ones are 4 spaces. The whitespace after skanner could be a different line ending. You can enable showing whitespace in preferences: General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Show whitespace characters

Comment: The new line differ (extra carriage return), but the spaces shows up identical and same amount (and no tab is used).

Comment: You should use a code formatter before checking in. Also you can set it per project and share it via SCM.

Comment: Offtopic: Well do you know any for Progress/OpenEdge? :p
http://www.oehive.org/node/757
Could not get that one to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to answer this one.

It was an extra carriage return on one side (PC newline, and the other had Mac/*nix), that would make it ignore the "ignore whitespace" setting for those lines.